# Xaml binding for conditional count

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I am creating a basic XX/YY control for an application, the total count is easy enough however I am having problems counting the XX which is based on a condition...

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="55"  Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="00" FontSize="40" Margin="5,0,5,5" />
        <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="40" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemList.Count, StringFormat={}{0:00}}" FontSize="40" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

the first textBlock should be Total count of ItemList where propertyX = 1

any ideas how I can set up the above binding for the first textblock.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show? The current page? the Current selected item?

Comment: @JPVenson count of items that a connection has been established to, each item has a connectionStatus enum (0-2) so when value == 1 count it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a converter to get the count.

```
public class ConditionalCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var output = 0;

        var collection = value as IEnumerable<MyConnectable>();

        if(collection != null)
        {
            output = collection.Count(i => i.connectionStatus == 1);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And reference it in your XAML as follows:

```
<UserControl xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceNameGoesHere">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:ConditionalCountConverter x:Key="CountConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl .Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemList, Converter={StaticResource CountConverter}}" />
</UserControl>
```

You can find additional [information about converters here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

What this does is creates an instance of your converter object that can be accessed by XAML. Then, when this field is renderer and the binding is executed, it passes the bound object into the converters `Convert` method, and the result is used instead of the object that was bound to. This is very powerful! Enjoy.

As some supplementary information, I personally consider this a "cheaty" use of converters because you're only implementing half of it. Generally, the result of your `Convert` method should be able to be passed directly into your `ConvertBack` method and converted into the source object it was derived from. This isn't always necessary; in this case we are sending the result to a display-only field. But if you were to have this object in a grid or editable control of some sort, you may want to implement it to go both ways so that a user could update a converted value and the proper thing would happen on the backend. That's just my two cents.

Comment: Though this approach is quite good, it doesn't cover cases when UI update is needed because the item's property `connectionStatus` was changed: typical collections (like `ObservableCollection`) don't send notifications about elements' properties changes, so binding to `ItemList` won't catch these updates.